# Extern C/C++ confusion in ndk - Syntax error Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk, extern

I wish to run a C Code in android for which I am using android ndk. I also need to add some libraries. While building these libraries, I am getting errors because of the extern statements in the header files. Eclipse IDE shows syntax errors. I also unchecked everything at Project-->Properties--> C/C++ Code Analysis.

Similar example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021335/aes-key-and-aes-block-size-cannot-be-resolved). How to resolve this?

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

Comment: The `extern "C"` should be used for method that will call throught jni, when building C++ code with the NDK.

If you don't build C++ code, you should not use `extern "C"`. If you want to build C++ code, make sure you source file is `.cpp` and that you add the appropriate flag in `Android.mk`. Also where in your projet is the code example you show ?

Comment: did you close the brace? `#ifdef __cplusplus } #endif`